# Does TimerTask run after I restart the android app from crash

Tags: android, timertask

I am making some api calls in the timer task. Suppose the app crashes or I go from current activity to another activity , timer task still keeps running? or should I restart the timertask if I move from one activity to another activty?

Answer (score 0):

> timer task still keeps running

No. It's gone with whole process once it crashes.

> or should I restart the timertask if I move from one activity to another activty?

That's bit different scenario from "crash" actually? You most likely have your app architectured wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an AlarmManager with a BroadcastReciver, that way you can set it up where it does not depend on the android life cycle and if it crashes you can program it to reset itself.